# Align a running list of expressions to the left

Tags: align

The following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \begin{flalign}
    J(1)=\\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} (h_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)^2=&&\\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} (\Theta_1(x^i)-y^i)^2=&&\\
    \frac{1}{3}((1-1)^2+(2-2)^2+(3-3)^2)=&&\\
    \frac{1}{3}(0+0+0)=0
  \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following equation alignment:

[image]

Aligning by the `=` is great when developing two sides of an equation. However, when developing an expresion line-by-line, I prefer that the expressions will be aligned to the left:

[image]

I assume that after seeing my handwriting skills, my need for Latex is self-explanatory.

## What have I tried

- Playing with `align` and `flalign`
- Reading "[Aligning equations with amsmath](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath)"
- Reading [problem using option fleqn in amsmath package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8740/problem-using-option-fleqn-in-amsmath-package), [Use flalign or alignat or align or similar environment to align to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/use-flalign-or-alignat-or-align-or-similar-environment-to-align-to-the-left), [Text in flalign/align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156193/text-in-flalign-align) and [How can I use an align environment flush left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28650/how-can-i-use-an-align-environment-flush-left)

## My question

How do I align a running numbered list of expressions, similar to the one listed above, in which the expressions are aligned to the left?

Comment: `flalign` (full length align) has nothing to do with `fleqn` (fixed length [from the margin] equations). Remember that `align` and the other environments with `align` in their name make columns in pair, the first right aligned and the second left aligned. So you just need `&` in front of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
    &J(1)=\\
    &\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} (h_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)^2=\\
    &\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} (\Theta_1(x^i)-y^i)^2=\\
    &\frac{1}{3}((1-1)^2+(2-2)^2+(3-3)^2)=\\
    &\frac{1}{3}(0+0+0)=0
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I changed `flalign` into `align`, because the former does nothing different in this case.