# Is "\\" the right way to start a new line in an align block?

Tags: line-breaking, align

I have been using `\\` to [start a new line in an align block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359359/align-a-running-list-of-expressions-to-the-left):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
    &J(1)=                                        & \text{Cost}\\
    &\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} (h_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)^2= & \text{Cost}\\
    &\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} (\Theta_1(x^i)-y^i)^2= & \text{Cost}\\
    &\frac{1}{3}((1-1)^2+(2-2)^2+(3-3)^2)=        & \text{Cost}\\
    &\frac{1}{3}(0+0+0)=                          & \text{Cost}\\
    &0
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

I've also seen this mark used in other code snippets like "[How to align a set of multiline equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations)".

I am trying to write good Latex. However, I did not find any reference as to whether this newline mark is a good practice within an `align` block. Furthermore, some answers (like "[Aligned equations in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74819/aligned-equations-in-latex)") use a single blackslash (`\`). This seem to have the same effect, but does not work for me.

**What's the right way to start a new line in an aligned block?**

Comment: The single backslash is a corruption by the system, it should be and originally was double. Double backslash is fine within `align`, the right way to do it in fact

Comment: Some posts on the site have been mangled by an unspecified bug turning ``\\<newline>`` into a single backslash with no newline. We're trying to fix them, but they're quite a large number. If you find a doubtful one, please, make a comment at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code

Comment: Thanks. Will do. So `\\` is the right answer?

Comment: @AdamMatan : you need to use two adjacent backslashes, \\ (hope that prints correctly).

Comment: To be clear ``\\`` is the right answer. Unfortunately the in-line markdown does funny things with backslashes, because the ``\`` is an escape character

Comment: If someone likes to post it as an answer I'll be happy to accept

Comment: Note that packages typically have documentation (writing `texdoc <packagename>` in a terminal is often the easiest way of finding it), so if you look in [`amsmath`'s docs](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), you'll see that `\\ ` is the way to go. @Au101 can write up an answer I suppose.

Comment: @AdamMatan "I actually typed two..." Yes I know =) What happened is the second backslash escaped the backtick and that's why you ended up with what you did, the correct input is double backtick double backslash double backtick: `` \\ `` but with no spaces: ``\\`` I just wanted to make it absolutely clear =)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I could but I didn't really say much in the comments. You're welcome to it, you'll be able to add more of interest with `texdoc` and stuff =)

Comment: @Au101 I was tempted to close as OT because the OP was confused by the double backslash bug of the site, and I don't really feel like answering. Nothing prevents you from mentioning documentation in an answer though.